# UITableView header shows up behind the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get this strange thing when I want to create an header to an `UITableView`:

[image: screenshot]

My code creating the header looks like this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec {

    return [self headerView];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)sec {
    NSLog(@"%f",[[self headerView] bounds].size.height);
    return [[self headerView] bounds].size.height;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    return [self init];
}

-(UIView *)headerView {
    //Falls headerView noch nicht geladen wurde ...
    if (!headerView) {
        //Lädt headerview.xib
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Is thos headerView that colored rectangle? How is this view set in xib? Did you set the height for the headerview in the delegate method?(heightForHeaderviewInsection:)

Comment: You never set headerView in your code.

Comment: This was a very stupid mistake.

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)sec {
    NSLog(@"%f",[[self headerView] bounds].size.height);
    return [[self headerView] bounds].size.height;
    }

heightForFooterInSection but I wanted to set the height.

The code has to look like this

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec {
    
    NSLog(@"%f",[[self headerView] bounds].size.height);
    return [[self headerView] bounds].size.height;
    }

Sorry for wasting everyones time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the height for header in section

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Try this hope this will help you.